# Insert Byte inside QByteArray from QString - Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, hex, qbytearray

I've little problem, I need to send trought modbus some bytes.
One from some, is: 0x04, and 0xFB

```
QString first, second;
first = "0x04";
second = "0xFB"

QByteArray array;
array[0] = first;
array[1] = second;
ecc...ecc..
```

Ho to solve ? 
I've tryed this:

```
array[0] = first.toUInt(nullptr,16);
```

but this last convert hex in other value.
How to solve ?

Comment: Please, have a look at [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#details). I believe, one of the examples shows exactly what you try to do.

Comment: Do you want to send `0x04` as byte, or do you want to send it as literal text `"0x04"`?

Comment: I want send 0x04 that is byte, ma this byte is generate from string, i need to converte it. I've used appena, but the final format of QByteArray is wrong....i need to insert the byte into qbytearray trough index. (array[0] = first;

Comment: OK, got it. [`QString::toUInt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUInt) can convert your hex number but: Either you have to remove the preceding `0x` (and use base 16) or you use base 0. You might have to convert the result of `QString::toUInt()` to `char` to eliminate resp. compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You can do convert the bytes directly to hex code and append it to the final bytearray like this:

```
QByteArray array;
array.append(QByteArray::fromHex("04"));
array.append(QByteArray::fromHex("FB"));
```

Or simply:

```
QByteArray array = QByteArray::fromHex("04FB");
```

Comment: with your solutions, array.append(QByteArray::fromHex(first)); don't work with QString variable.

Comment: To use this solution with QString variable you'll need convert it first to QByteArray using one of the following methods:

`QString::toLatin1(),
QString::toAscii(),
QString::toLocal8Bit()`.

Like this:

`array.append(QByteArray::fromHex(first.toLocal8Bit()+second.toLocal8Bit()));`

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
QByteArray array=first.toLatin1() + second.toLatin1();
array.replace("0x","");
array= QByteArray::fromHex(array);
```